# GCE NGINX Ingress does not use controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, controller, ingress

I've installed nginx ingress using helm on Google Cloud Kubernetes. The service, controller and default backend are up and running and I can perform a GET request on the /healthz endpoint. However, when I try to setup my Ingress, it shows a different load balancer IP than the controller does. In my case the controller shows 35.246.249.9 (port 80 and 443) and the Ingress shows 35.246.171.243. When I try to connect to the second IP, the connection gets refused.

This is my Ingress yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-integration
  namespace: integration
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: website-com
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: website.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: website
          servicePort: 4000
```

Ingress description:

```
Name:             ingress-nginx-integration
Namespace:        integration
Address:          35.246.171.243
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.20.2.8:8080)
Rules:
  Host                         Path  Backends
  ----                         ----  --------
  website.com    
                                  website:4000 (<none>)
Annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name:       website-com
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:        /
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect:          false
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  ....
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:  nginx
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                  From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                 ----                      -------
  Normal  UPDATE  18m (x9 over 58m)    nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress integration/ingress-nginx-integration
  Normal  DELETE  6m34s                nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress integration/ingress-nginx-integration
  Normal  CREATE  2m16s (x2 over 59m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress integration/ingress-nginx-integration
```

Controller description:

```
Name:                     nginx-ingress-controller
Namespace:                integration
Labels:                   app=nginx-ingress
                          chart=nginx-ingress-1.1.5
                          component=controller
                          heritage=Tiller
                          release=nginx-ingress
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=nginx-ingress,component=controller,release=nginx-ingress
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.23.243.186
LoadBalancer Ingress:     35.246.249.9
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30996/TCP
Endpoints:                10.20.2.62:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  32752/TCP
Endpoints:                10.20.2.62:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Both, Ingress and controller, run inside the "integration" namespace. I followed this tutorial for the most part: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke Everything worked before, when I used the default gce ingress controller, but I need http -> https redirects.

Why does it show a different load balancer IP, is that correct? And if so, why does it refuse connections?

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Ok my setup is correct. It looks like it takes quite a while before everything sorts out itself. After waiting 12 hours, it's all running fine now.